# prevent git pull asking for username password from github when remote repository not found

Tags: git, github, https, http-status-code-404

I've looked at all the questions about configuring username / password for 'git pull', but none address the issue when the remote repository is 404.

I've git clone'd a repository from github sometime in the past.  For whatever reason, the repository owner has deleted the repo, and git pull fails.  Before it fails though, git pull asks for username and password.

This happens because I have a directory of cloned github git repos, and I'm trying to update them all by shell script that goes into each directory and does a 'git pull'.

```
$ git pull
ksshaskpass: cannot connect to X server 
error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass'
Username for 'https://github.com': 
ksshaskpass: cannot connect to X server 
error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass'
Password for 'https://github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/[ ... ]
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the remote for the repository that's gone missing?

Comment: You can use credential-less login using ssh keys. That will not ask you for credentials. If this is something you want to do...

Answer (score 3):

I've found myself in a similar situation, and my solution was to set a fake credential provider for Git by doing:

```
export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/true"
```

This causes the pull / clone to fail immediately rather than prompting for a username and password. It's a bit of a hack, but I couldn't find any other simple way of preventing the prompt.

Comment: Alas, does not work for me. It still asks for credentials. There might something wrong with my system configuration. I've noticed that redirecting stdout and stderr to /dev/null still gives me a password prompt. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

I created this script to test the url prior to doing a pull.
I no longer get prompted for username/password while updating.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f | egrep '\.git/config' | while read fn ; do \
    dn=${fn%/.git/config} 
    url=$( git -C $dn remote show -n origin | awk '/Fetch URL: / { print $3 }' ) 
    wiki=${url%.wiki.git}
    if [ "$url" != "$wiki" ]; then
        url="${wiki}/wiki"
    fi
    url=$( echo $url | sed -e 's/git:/https:/' )
    wget -O /dev/null $url > /dev/null 2>&1  
    if [ 0 != $? ]; then 
        echo $dn $url 
    else 
        pushd $dn
        git pull
        popd
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was hitting prompts during `git fetch` for repositories which did not exist on GitHub.

these prompted despite input and output being piped (likely `git` internally tries for `/dev/tty`)

I adjusted my command by configuring `core.askPass` to a dummy value (I picked `/bin/true` which exits zero and produces no output)

Here's the command I ended up with:

```sh
git -c core.askPass=/bin/true fetch origin ...
```